# Included .hpp files for openCV, but C++ drawing functions not found

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv

I've installed openCV on my machine, and imported the `.hpp` files, but I keep getting "use of undeclared identifier" errors when using the C++ drawing functions like `circle()`, `line()` etc.  The weird part is the compiler recommends the C version of the function like `Did you mean cvCircle()?`

I'm using Xcode, and created a C++ command line project. `main.cpp` is the only file in the project other than the included openCV files.

I'm using the following [tutorial](http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/2013/10/basic-drawing-examples.html) to learn openCV, so I don't think there's a problem in my code, but it looks like this:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main( )
{
    // Create black empty images
    Mat image = Mat::zeros( 400, 400, CV_8UC3 );

    // Draw a line
    line( image, Point( 15, 20 ), Point( 70, 50), Scalar( 110, 220, 0 ),  2, 8 );
    imshow("Image",image);

    waitKey( 0 );
    return(0);
}
```

Is it possible I've downloaded openCV incorrectly?  The `.hpp` files import properly, so I don't see why the C++ functions can't be called.  If there are any other details I should add to the question let me know.

Comment: This is apparently about C++, not C. Don't add unrelated tags.

Comment: @Olaf I thought this was related to C since the compiler seems to think I'm using C.

Comment: Just because it give that hint does not mean it compiles as C. Maybe you better add an xcode tag. I can't help here, but I suspect there is information missing in your question.

Answer (score 0):

For calling the function line(), you also need to include the improc.hpp.

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
```